# What font is used for keyboard symbols?

Tags: keyboard, font

I'm looking for the font that Apple is using for [Special Key Symbols](http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2005/05/special-key-symbols.html) on their keyboards. I know that [Vag Rounded](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFont&code=VAGQ10003000) is used for regular characters, but that font does not support characters used for the special keys. I've been searching for a font that would look at least similar to the symbols, but so far I haven't found anything satisfying. For example, here are some of the keys with the special symbols:

Return(↩) key:
[image: return key]

Tab(⇥), Caps Lock(⇪), Shift(⇧), Alt(⌥), Command(⌘) keys:
[image: various keys]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Apple Symbols.  Glyph 1009 in that one has similar corners.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could find that symbols in emoji keyboard. Just type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and search for it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately none of the installed fonts look like the symbols on the keyboard. For example, the return key symbol is always curved, whereas on the keyboard it has sharp corners.